# how to find elements in an array exported from firestore in BigQuery

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, google-bigquery, firebase-extensions

i need to get count of item has been sold so iam exporting my firestore data to big query
i have collection in firestore and i have array of object
[image]

i need to export forestore data to big query

```
line_items
[
  {
    price:10,
    qyt:2,
   name:car
   },
 { 
   price:4,
   qyt:1,
   name:pen
  },
 ]
```

i have created schema.json
and added the type as array and exported the collection data

```
  {
    "name": "line_items",
    "type": "array"
  }
```

now iam trying to write query  in cloud.google to get this result in

```
name |qty
car  | 2
pen  | 1
```

my issue im not able to convert my array of object to columns so i can get the counts of item qty has been sold

[image]

this is how the data looks in big query it is not showing as array of object

[image]

Comment: It might that you haven't unnested your data. but It kind of looks like your schema is wrong. Can you share the errors you are getting and shot of the schema as it appear in bigquery?

Comment: this is my schema i have defined line_items as array. https://pasteboard.co/0jZLFeL8aqzU.png

Comment: the error is Cannot access field barcode on a value with type ARRAY<STRING> at [2:19]
i think im getting array of string that is why i can not unset check:https://www.photobox.co.uk/my/photo/full?photo_id=504281597889

Comment: Unfortunately I can see that image. 
You've probably read this https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/loading-data-cloud-firestore#cloud_firestore_options might be worth a quick read if not.
You shouldn't have to create the schema if importing from firestore. 

A `map` in firestore is a `record` type in bigquery, so your schema isn't right.

Answer (score 0):

You have to `UNNEST` an array before getting elements

```
SELECT name, qty FROM your_dataset.your_table, UNNEST(line_items)
```

Comment: that is not working. Unrecognized name: qty at [2:8]

Comment: the thing line_items is coming as json , but i have defined as array when i created  the view